# Matching permission ids between Node.js server and MySQL database

Tags: javascript, sql, mysql, database, mariadb

I have a database that is structured as follows (I'm not set on the structure, it's just what I've come up with. it's also not inclusive of all columns):

| Table | Columns |
| --- | --- |
| permission_project | (id, name) |
| user | (id) |
| project | (id) |
| project_user_permission | (project_id, permission_id, user_id) |

(ID columns with prefixes are FKs)
In my application code, I will want to reference the permission values to authorize user/api actions, and as such I want to ensure the JS values are in sync with the database values. However, I'm unsure of the best methodology for this.

I've come up with three potential solutions (with varying feelings about them):

1. Define and populate the permissions table within the application code, ensuring the application's values are authoritative (I don't know if this is practical. Also concerns me regarding potentially invalidating data and mixing up permissions).
2. Populate a JS object with the contents of the permissions table, and refer to this object when querying permissions (I don't like that this requires updating the permission names everywhere they're used in the application if the database content changes)
3. Map database permission names to application permission names, then populate a JS object with the application permission names. This at least narrows the maintenance of solution 2 down to a single point, but I'm not jumping for joy at having to change permission names in two separate locations.

Are any of these solutions practical? Is there a better solution that I'm not aware of?
As mentioned earlier, I'm not married to the structure. I'm happy to modify the database if it can be improved.